# MS Access - Database Version, what they mean?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

**Is there a table of version with what they mean?**
[Only thing I could find](https://www.freelanceaccessdeveloper.co.uk/accessversions.asp)

Today I got this message from one of the PC's that use the company DataBase: "Database you are trying to open requires a newer version of Microsoft Access".
[Info about this message here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-requires-newer-access)

This PC and My computer use the same version of Office (2016 Professional) and we are both updated and the Database was created on my computer.

Later today, at home, my research came across 'currentdb.version', the core of my question here.

---

I ran some testes on access console

Main Database

```
?currentdb.version
32
```

After 'Compact and repair'

```
?currentdb.version
16.7
```

Remove 'Big Numbers' and 'Compact and repair'

```
?currentdb.version
12.0
```

I can't find any information about this versions number, what they mean? whats the requirement? why 'compact and repair' affect it? Why two computers with **same** version of office behave different?

The build version of access in each computer is different, but i got no control over it. Windows update says both are up to date.

Unfortunately I could not test if the 'compact and repair', witch resulted in a lower version number, solved the problem because today is Saturday and I have no access to the computer now.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

Removing 'Big Number' from database and doing 'Compact and Repair' solved the problem, now the client computer can connect. I still don't understand why this happened, both computers use the same version of office and are up to date. The client computer used to connect to the database before, and the 'big number' was there at the time. There is something else going on, but I got no time to figure it out.

Thanx everyone.

Comment: List does not show beyond 2018. Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-version-property-dao and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Application.CurrentDb. Compact & Repair did not change the output for my db because I did not C&R a db built with a different version.

Comment: No idea why you get numbers 32 and 16.7 https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/history/versions.htm

Comment: Database versions have been uncoupled from Office versions for a short while, however, as far as I know, this is undocumented as of yet. 32.0 essentially means "uses new datetime extended field" and these versions are lowered on compact and repair if that data type is no longer used. 16.7 corresponds to "uses the large number type, but not datetime extended"

Comment: @June7 Unfortunately, those resources are outdated, and no-one has made a proper up to date one as far as I know. As hinted by my comment, you get 16.7 for a database with a large number field but no datetime extended field, and 32.0 for a database with a datetime extended field

Comment: @ErikA I believe you are right. But how come one of the computers with same office version cant open the file? Tomorrow I'll test if the lower version number solved the problem and update this thread.

Comment: The same version as in same build number? Microsoft has decided to make substantial changes to Access within the same main release (2016 may or may not have support for the large number type based on the build number, and the same goes for 2021 and date time extended)

Comment: I run 2010 and get 14 which is version number for Access 2010. 12 is for Access 2007.